# psexec command to run bat file present in some directory on remote server

Tags: remote-access, psexec

I want to achieve following in one single command.

**PS D:\custom> .\PsExec.exe \remoteserver -u user -p password -accepteula -s cmd
PsExec v2.34 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2021 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - [www.sysinternals.com](http://www.sysinternals.com)
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
C:\Windows\system32>D:
D:\ cd test
D:\test>testjob.bat
D:\test>hostname
windowsrundeck**

I don't want to copy my bat file from my local machine to remote machine. instead I want to directly execute a bat file present in D:\test folder of remote machine.

Also, Is it possible to run multiple commands in one psexec command ?

Also, If I use this psexec command in automation tool, it just gives me exit code, note verbose of what it has done.. How can I see what my bat file is doing when I run my psexec command from automation tool?

Comment: I managed to fix it by adding all commands in one bat file. 
and I was able to execute the batfile in D:\test by using -w parameter in psexec command.
 -w sets the working directory on remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it by adding all commands in one bat file. and I was able to execute the batfile in D:\test by using -w parameter in psexec command. -w sets the working directory on remote machine.